# Can I add Google Analytics Custom Dimensions from the Console?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

As the title says, can I create GA from the console and send over custom dimensions?

I'm looking to try from the console so that I'm working with the production site, but the dimension1 value doesn't show up in my report.

I've tried:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'none');
ga('set', 'dimension1', '1');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

We're trying to send a custom dimension across to see which homepage the user was presented with to determine which one works best. Problem is that I can't get it to send across the custom dimension.

I've created the CD in the Dashboard and a Report which has it as a dimension of the pages visited but no joy. This is my first time working with GA!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send custom dimensions from the console (it's just javascript after all) as long as you make sure that the analytics library is loaded (which is not clear from your example) and that you send an interaction hit after you set the dimension (which you are doing). Also the dimension must be set up in the property settings of the property you send the value to.

Remember that GA needs some processing time before all data becomes available, so it might take up to 24 hours (usually it's much quicker, though) before you can see the values.

I would recommend to use either the network tab in your browser (look for a call to google-analytics.com/collect) or the Chrome Ga debugger extension to see if the data is actually being sent.

Comment: Cheers, I have the extension and when calling it does appear to get sent to the server. Perhaps just a test of time?

Comment: Yup, there is the "cd1" parameter in the call. I guess you have to wait a bit (and while you probably know that, remember that custom dimensions do not show up by default - set them as secondary dimension or create a custom report based on their value).

Comment: Custom dimension data appeared on the dashboard today! Many thanks for your help.